# Can I add static HTML/Javascript/jQuery file to wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a big html file that uses `Javascript`, `jQuery,` `c3.js`,  `style.css`, `normalize.css`...

The question is: Can I add it as a static html to *wordpress*?
For example the file is *calculator.html*, and I need it at *www.company.com/calculator.html*.

Its a webpage of a company and I dont even have any files of the webpage, so I cant test. I created a free WP account to test but I didnt manage to do it, since it is supposed to be uploaded at the "wordpress root" but I dont find it. So I dont know if as a free account I dont have all the features or its not possible.

Comment: have you tried pasting your title into google?

Comment: you must add it from file manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding other css files to wp\_head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519573/adding-other-css-files-to-wp-head)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template (as part of the theme you are using) and then create a static calculator page within your backend where you select your template as the page's template.

**1. Create template**

**2. Add template to page**

**3. Set the shortlink of the page to www.company.com/calculator.html**

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/?utm_expid=3606929-74.aeX0WyvtRVa7qMe8Ph5smw.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F

You need to fill the template file with the calculator HTML code.