# <?php wp_head(); ?> function not including functions from functions.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have trouble concerning wordpress, and its  function, I have been trying to include a css file in the functions.php like so:

```
function alien_includer() {

wp_enqueue_style('customstyles', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/css/alien.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alien_includer');

?>
```

So the problem is thatI have not managed to include the css sheet, even though I have written the header.php like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The best Theme</title>
<!--php functions-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
```

I would appreciate some help alot. Yes, I have looked around, similar problems may be solved by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519573/adding-other-css-files-to-wp-head)

But it didn't help me.

****EDIT****
[Am not alowed to add pictures just yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtFya.png)

Comment: It has nothing to do with wp_head()

Comment: Do you know what the problem is then?

Comment: I added an answer below paste that and modify the path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this link

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

If you need still help and not getting problem solved then send me query to my mail ashok[dot]amn [at] gmail

I will reply you but don't forget to attach code OR live link with access.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official way to add custom script or stylesheets on Wordpress

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_files', 11);
function load_custom_files() {
    //external scripts
    wp_enqueue_style('file-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-styles.min.css', array(), null, 'all');
}
```

In your, css file add this

```
body {
   display: none;
}
```

Just to test if it was imported or not.

[Wp enqueue javascript files reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

[Wp enqueue stylesheet files reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Comment: I tried replacing mine with yours: it's here: https://codeanywhere.com/s/l/dLEhjpqguui0Jgtmzzie7oLCdh4SxKFUCtqnjQCrGoEgiKCwwlNKQyOTJVKHAYj5

Comment: what is not working? Any error? if yes share the error screenshot

Comment: No error, it just didn't output anything: shared screenshot.

Comment: Make sure that you are putting the code inside `functions.php` file and your path are correct.

Comment: I definitely am.

Comment: Strange never happened to me, still I updated and added a debugging test in my answer.

Comment: I still see no change, not sure howdisplay:none; is working

Comment: `display: none` should show a blank white screen. Did you try a hard reload to cache busting?? If not press ctrl + F5 or cmd + F5. Make sure the css code is in the new css file that you are importing.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything, even hardcoded the adress for the css file this time.

Comment: Remove the last parameter 'all' from the code above any try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are enqueing the script correctly, but I think it isn't finding your folder structure.

You can bug fix this by right clicking on the webpage in chrome and selecting 'inspect', and along the top bar of the inspect section which should have just popped up you'll see one option for 'Console' - click on this and it will show the files called which are have errors, and which file structure they are trying to be called from.

Comment: Console is empty.

Comment: Try without the get_template_directory_uri() and hardcode it with the url just to test it?

                       

wp_enqueue_style('customstyles', 'http://www.mywebsite.com/css/alien.css', array(), 'null', 'all');

Comment: Maybe try 'null' where you have version 1.0.0 in case it's not updating due to you needing a newer version???

Comment: '1.0.0', 'all');         replace with      'null', 'all');

Comment: Still see nothing.

Comment: might be you're doing something silly i.e editing the wrong theme, website - try just thinking outside the box

Comment: That seems unlikely, am running this in a vanilla wordpress instance on codeanywhere. Looking everything over it seems to be where it should be.

Comment: Maybe again just for testing  but hook the css just in script tags to wp_head hook:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head